# blueimp jquery file upload with Sails.js?

Tags: jquery, file, sails.js, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

How to modify or implement blueimp jquery-file-upload in sails.js? Actually the blueimp jQuery file upload is for node.js so I want to convert it to for sails.js as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? You should be able to upload a file using blueimp or any library out of the box using regular controller actions.